# Online Ruby Code Challenge with built in testing

Tags: ruby

I came across this link yesterday: http://toys.usvsth3m.com/javascript-under-pressure/

Its a javascript code challenge with integrated testing.

I have 2 questions about this:

- Does anyone know of something similar for ruby?
- How would you approach building something like this?

I would love something like this to help sharpen my ruby skills. And I think it would be very useful for many people learning ruby. If it doesn't exist, I may like to try building it.

Comment: Looks like a great idea! There would be an obvious lag when validating Ruby answers because you'll need a server to run the tests. You could speed things up by using a Ruby VM written in JS, like: http://repl.it/languages/Ruby (beta). Doubt test frameworks would run reliably under that, however.

Comment: Actually, I did find this similar website a while back: http://rexaminator.com/exams/new

Comment: This turned up on Linked In recently: http://www.codewars.com/?language=ruby I tried the front page, but didn't sign up, so don't know what the purpose or affiliation is.

Comment: Thanks for the links I think the rexaminator.com one comes close to what I am looking for.

Comment: codewars used to have a code timer but its since been removed. It still has a fastest time leaderboard for each of the code challenges, but the emphasis is not on speed.

Comment: In the [SaaS Online Course](https://www.edx.org/course/berkeley/cs169-1x/software-service/1136) Ruby challenges are automatically graded. If I remember correctly, the RubyMonk tutorial site does something like that. In essence, they're running your code through predefined test scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

That is a awesome website that am definitely going to start using. As for Ruby I know
one website which is not exactly the same but it's pretty cool.
Its called exercism.io and it was built by my teacher from Jumpstart Labs. You should 
check it out as its a great way to learn how to write great code in ruby and various 
other languages.